# IsolatedStorage Not Working With IE Protected Mode? C#

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, save, isolatedstorage

Using **IsolatedStorage** with IE **Protected Mode**.

I am building a C# .NET (VS2010) IE8 add-on application but am having some trouble saving data using IsolatedStorage on a Windows 7 64-bit machine, *when* Internet Explorer's default Protected Mode is enabled.

*(I am switching to this method from using Settings as Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); which also failed with IE Protected Mode on. I also tried saving files in LocalLow with no luck either.)*

Could anyone point out how I can amend the following code please to enable it to work with IE Protected Mode? I have tried so many ideas and nothing so far has worked. Surely there must be a way to save data??

```
//FileIOPermission perm = new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted); 
    //perm.Assert(); 
    //perm.Demand();  

//---Write---
IsolatedStorageFile app_isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(
    IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);
IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(
    "app_started.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, app_isoStore);

StreamWriter iswriter = new StreamWriter(isoStream);
iswriter.WriteLine("Run");
iswriter.Close();

//app_isoStore.Dispose();
app_isoStore.Close();

//---Read---
IsolatedStorageFile app_isoStoreCheck = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(
    IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);
IsolatedStorageFileStream isoReadStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(
    "app_started.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, app_isoStoreCheck);

StreamReader isreader = new StreamReader(isoReadStream);
string rdata = isreader.ReadToEnd();
isreader.Close();

//app_isoStoreCheck.Dispose();
app_isoStoreCheck.Close();
```

Comment: I copied your code exactly as you wrote it in your example, and it works fine. It reads the value "Run" from the file.  It also works if I close the program, comment out the part that writes, and then run the program again to read the data.  Works as expected.  Try single-stepping your program to verify that it is or isn't working.

Comment: Wait, you said "IE8 Application".  Is this a Web service?  I did mine as a standalone Console program.  I suppose it's possible that there's some difference. I don't have a way to easily test this as a Web service or ASP.NET page, or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for testing it. I tried placing an output after every line and it didn't call an exception, so it appeared as if it should have worked. I just can't see why it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't providing any the evidence arguments.

Have you tried the following overloads instead of `GetStore`:

- GetUserStoreForApplication
- GetUserStoreForUser
- GetUserStoreForDomain
- GetMachineStoreForApplication
- GetMachineStoreForUser
- GetMachineStoreForDomain

What operating system are you using?  What version of .NET are you using?  What file system type are you executing this on?  Are you the administrator of the machine?  What is the IsolatedStorage policy on the machine?  Is it enabled? How much space does each user have?

Can you observe the `app_started.txt` file being created in the appropriate directory?  If not then you might also have a permissions issue... NTFS ACL etc...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(v=vs.80).aspx

Just some suggestions.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using .NET Framework 4.0. GetUserStoreForUser() failed with an exception. The file is not being created. The problem occurs on an NTFS 64-bit Windows 7 machine. I had not looked into the policy as I only just started using IsolatedStorage as I was told it was a method that would always work and that I should switch to it instead of using the Visual Studio Settings method that had proved unable to run under the default IE Protected Mode.

Comment: IsolatedStorage will not always work.  The user can block it, as well as other reasons.